# AndEngine SceneTouchEvent 

Tags: android, andengine

I am using AndEngines onSceneTouchEvent method to create a jump affect for  a sprite.

The issue i am having is that if the user touches the screen for instance they triple tap the screen the sprite will keep jumping, what i want is for it to receive only 1 click and do one jump for the one touch.

Here is what i am using which is causing this issue.
As you see i try to use a mIsJumping boolean and when the player collides with a invisible rectangle, it is set to false again to allow for jumping again.

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()){

             if(mIsJumping == false){
                    SequenceEntityModifier jumpModifier = new SequenceEntityModifier(
                                new MoveYModifier(.6f, player.getY(), player.getY() - 250, EaseQuadOut.getInstance()),
                                new MoveYModifier(.6f, player.getY() - 250, player.getY(), EaseBounceOut.getInstance()));
                        player.registerEntityModifier(jumpModifier);

            }


    }



    return false;
}
```

From my description above how can i only register one touch even and jump once until the sprite collides with the rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's even an easier solution - use an `IEntityModifierListener`.

Create the listener this way:

```
final IEntityModifier.IEntityModifierListener listener = new IEntityModifier.IEntityModifierListener() {

        @Override
        public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier,
                IEntity pItem) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onModifierFinished(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier,
                    IEntity pItem) {
            mIsJumping = false;

        }

};
```

Register it to the `MoveYModifier` that moves the player down. So, when the modifying ends (The jump modification ends), `mIsJumping` will be false. Also, remember to set `mIsJumping` to `true` when the jump starts.